# Micro instance hangs during yum update

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've used the CentOS 6 image. Twice, the micro instance (1 vCPU, 0.6 GB memory) hangs during the yum update:

```
Updating   : selinux-policy-targeted-3.7.19-231.el6.noarch
```

CPUs shoots up to 120%. I've waited over 20 minutes, the instance is compeltey unresponsible. I've tried a secod time with a new micro instance, same thing.

Is there any way to keep CentOS up to date on a micro instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julien, are you using a small disk? If so, is it possible that the update is so large that you're exceeding the performance limits on the disk? Please see https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdperformance

Comment: I choose the default CentOS image: 10GB

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. If this is the case, I would argue that perhaps CentOS and RHEL should not be allowed to launch on micro instances, because apparently _any_ yum update might lock your machine up for hours, which is a pretty terrible user experience.

Comment: I am having the exact problem
Centos / 10 GB / micro instance

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the same.

If you do a `gcutil getserialportoutput` for the instance during the hang you'll see many "Out of memory" errors.

I suspect the `0.6GB` of memory is too small, at least for `yum update`.

Comment: I have multiple VPS with 512MB RAM, yum update works just fine.